# Show that the sequence $x_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$x_n = 1 + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{4^2} + \dotsb + \frac{n}{4^{n-1}}$$

So I need to see if the sequence is monotone and bounded. By doing $x_{n+1} - x_n$ I get $\frac{n+1}{4^n} > 0$ so its increasing. How do I show that it is bounded? Also I have a hint to use the $2^n > n$ inequality.

Comment: This is an arithmetico-geometric series,

Comment: I am curious why didn't you mark any one of the four answers as correct?

Comment: @xXACEXx Sorry for the late response, there was a timer cap of about ~ 15 minutes, after you answered i checked it and it said to wait a couple of minutes and literally forgot about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Note]** :
$$
1 + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{4^2} + \frac{4}{4^{3}}+\cdots + \frac{n}{4^{n-1}}
$$
$$
\leq
$$
$$
1+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{4}+\cdots+\frac{n}{4(n-1)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use $$n\leq 2^n\leq 4^n$$ which implies $$\frac{n}{4^n}\leq \frac{2^n}{4^n}=\frac{2^n}{(2^{n})^2}=\frac{1}{2^n}\leq 1$$ and use the comparison test, as $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}=2 $$ is a convergent geometric series. You might need to make some slight edits, as this isn't your exact series, but the same principle will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** When $n$ is large enough we have
$$
\frac{n}{4^{n-1}} <\frac{1}{2^n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k y^{n-1}=\frac d {dy}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n  y^{n}\right)=\frac d {dy}\left(\frac{y \left(y^n-1\right)}{y-1}\right)$$
$$x_n=\frac{(n (y-1)-1) y^n+1}{(y-1)^2}$$Now, let $y=\frac 14$ to obtain after expansion
$$x_n=\frac{16}{9}-\frac{1}{3} 4^{1-n} n-\frac{4^{2-n}}{9}$$